# Xcode 4 workflow when working on same iOS project with multiple developers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

Can anyone help me with providing a flawless or an official workflow of working with multiple devs on an iOS project under a version control [GIT/SVN].

With the storyboards, I can't see having a developer lock, if two of them modify the storyboard, there is a merge conflict. Xcode XML files aren't nice to merge and often causes merge problem and will in fact corrupt.       It would be really interesting to know how Apple manages this with their internal teams, it sure would help us.

Answer (score 0):

How difficult it is to merge things depends on the quality of your merge tool.  Conflicts are inevitable without signing out (locking) code.  Here is what I did.  I realized that everyone is going to be editing at once, so I gave up on storyboards and just went back to XIB files.  They are more decentralized and make it easier to edit two parts at once (actually now, I even got away from NIB files and use even more abstract formats that the XIB files load).  Also, I don't know if your team is local or not but my team was and we gave each other notices that we would be editing files.  We had some conflicts, but P4Merge made it very easy to handle them (even in XML files).  You just need to get used to what you are looking at

Answer (score 0):

As you say, the XML files are a pain.  We've found the following helps:

1. Have each developer work on their own branch, so you only have to merge once.
2. Avoid NIBs and storyboards - put all your view code in view classes and perform all the transitions in your controller code.
3. Keep your groups sorted by name; this reduces the number of project file conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

What we normally do at my studio is set up an SVN repository with the following layout:

-/Root Project Folder 
==/Dev1Sources 
====/Sources 
====/Views
==/Dev2Sources
====/Sources
====/Views
... etc 
-/Shared Libraries

Big thing to note DO NOT use interface builder to bind the variables and controls. You have to tell your developers to instantiate delegates and bindings programatically. Else it tends to make tons of issues when integrating.

Make use of the following tools:
-Trello. Project management collaboration tool. Add the tasks you want done, and whenever the module gets finished the developers are notified, etc.
-Apigee. API documentation tool. Write your expected I/O API's so everyone in your project knows what and how to pass info back and forth. GREATLY reduces API issues and development downtime.

Follow some agile / lean development business practices to cut expenditures and increase development success, speed, etc.

Last but not least this is how a day gets broken down in the studio.

0-1st hour = Team meeting. Devs should update the entire directory to latest version. 
2nd-4th hr = Development 
LUNCH 
5th-7th hr = Development 
7th-8th hr = API Documentation and Team Debrief

It's a well oiled machine down here. lol